# why i get null when intent double value

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-intent, double

I need to intent a double value in order to insert in SQLite but when i print output it show NULL value.

This is code intent in first Activity

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Process.this,AddStudent.class);
    intent.putExtra("Intent", result);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and this is code get intent in another activity

```
    String concentrate = getIntent().getStringExtra("Intent");
```

Here is full code.
FirstActivity;

public class Process extends Activity {

```
public static double a,b,r,std_err = 0.0;
public static double e;
public static int N;




@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_process);

    double[] x = { 10,30,50,60,90,55 };
    double[] y = { 1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };

    Process model = new Process();
    model.Regression(x, y);
    double result = Math.pow(2.71828182845904,x[0]*b);  // e^bx 

    Intent intent = new Intent(Process.this,AddStudent.class);
    intent.putExtra("Intent", result);
    startActivity(intent);


}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

public static void Regression (double[] oat, double[] energy) {

    N = oat.length;

    // constant e:
    Double e = Math.E;

    Double sumX = 0.00;
    Double sumX2 = 0.00;
    Double sumY = 0.00;
    Double sumYlin = 0.00;
    Double sumY2 = 0.00;
    Double sumY2lin = 0.00;
    Double sumXY = 0.00;
    Double sumXYlin = 0.00;

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
            sumX = sumX + oat[i];
            sumX2 = sumX2 + Math.pow(oat[i], 2);

            // exponential
            sumY = sumY + Math.log(energy[i]);
            sumY2 = sumY2 + Math.pow(Math.log(energy[i]), 2);
            sumXY = sumXY + (oat[i]*(Math.log(energy[i])));

    }

    b = ((N*sumXY) - (sumX*sumY))/(N*sumX2 - (sumX*sumX));
    a = Math.pow(e, (sumY - (b*sumX))/N);


    Double c = 0.00;        // numerator
    Double d = 0.00;        // denominator

    c = (b)*(sumXY - sumX*sumY/N);
    d = sumY2 - (sumY*sumY)/N;
    r = c/d;

    Double p = 0.00;
    if(r > 0){
            p = Math.sqrt(r);
    } else {
            p = 0.00;
    }


    std_err = Math.sqrt((d-c)/(N-2));


    }
}
```

SecondActivity; the activity for add data in SQLite

```
public class AddStudent extends Activity {
DatabaseStudent mHelper;
SQLiteDatabase mDb;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add);

    mHelper = new DatabaseStudent(this);
    mDb = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    final EditText editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
    final EditText editLastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editLastName);
    final EditText editSchool = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSchool);

    Button buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = editName.getText().toString();
            String lastname = editLastName.getText().toString();
            String school = editSchool.getText().toString();
            //concentrate
            //String concentrate = getIntent().getStringExtra("Intent");
            String concentrate = getIntent().getStringExtra("Intent");

            //Date&Time
            java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
            java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
                 new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);

            if(name.length() != 0 && lastname.length() != 0 
                    && school.length() != 0 ) {

                Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " 
                        + DatabaseStudent.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " 
                        + DatabaseStudent.COL_NAME + "='" + name + "'" 
                        + " AND " + DatabaseStudent.COL_LASTNAME + "='" 
                        + concentrate + "'" + " AND " 
                        + DatabaseStudent.COL_SCHOOL + "='" + currentTime //add COL_SCHOOL = currentTime
                        + "'", null);

                if(mCursor.getCount() == 0) {
                    mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DatabaseStudent.TABLE_NAME 
                            + " (" + DatabaseStudent.COL_NAME 
                            + ", " + DatabaseStudent.COL_LASTNAME  
                            + ", " + DatabaseStudent.COL_SCHOOL 
                            + ") VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + concentrate //result ไม่มา
                            + "', '" + currentTime + "');"); 



                    editName.setText("");
                    editLastName.setText("");
                    editSchool.setText("");

        }
    });
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mHelper.close();
    mDb.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Please try debugging code.. and first do some research..!!

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
   double result = Math.pow(2.71828182845904,x[0]*b);
```

and

```
   intent.putExtra("Intent", result);
```

`result` is a `double`.

But when you retrieve you have

```
   String concentrate = getIntent().getStringExtra("Intent");
```

Instead you should use

```
   double concentrate = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("Intent", 0);
```

Reference :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getDoubleExtra(java.lang.String, double)

Comment: I was good because i did't get Null value. But i got value equal 0.0, I think that it must cause from ("Intent", 0) because when i change from 0 to 5 like this ("Intent", 5) it will show 5.0. How can i get the real value of "Intent" from firstactivity

Comment: @user3101751 simply means that result has no value in the previous activity. If there is no value the default value is used. that is why you got 5 or 0. in the first case  was the default value in the second it was 5.

Comment: @user3101751 did you even check the link i posted has an explanation

Comment: How is it possible that i intent "double result" not pass.

Comment: @user3101751 log the value of result in the previous activity and check the logcat.

Comment: Then you are not passing it from the first `Activity` or the key you try to match is different than that passed in the first `Activity`. Case matters so check that they have the same upper case and lower case letters

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually placing your double value into your `Intent`. You need to use `putDouble` and `getDouble` methods.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Process.this,AddStudent.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putDouble("Intent", result);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, get it in your next Activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
double result = b.getDouble("Intent");
```

Comment: i've tried working with bundle but it got error. I can't run application. I don't know why it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
String concentrate = getIntent().getStringExtra("Intent");
```

Should be like this:

```
double concentrate = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("Intent");
```

Wrap the passed bundle directly into double.

Comment: It has a red line under "getDouble" the error show "The method getDouble(String) is undefined for the type Intent" How can i fix it.

Comment: please put this statement `double concentrate = getIntent().getDouble("Intent");` outside the `buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {});`

Comment: It is still occur the same problem.

Comment: Sorry my bad.. Typo Error.. please see the edit. it should be
double concentrate = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("Intent");

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `Double` value and trying to get a `String` value so you are getting null

Replace

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("Intent");
```

with

```
getIntent().getDoubleExtra("Intent", 0);
```

Comment: ("Intent", 0) what does it mean? because when i change from 0 to 5. it will show value equal 5 not a real value.

Comment: It is the default value that will be selected when there is no key for `Intent`

Comment: that mean, if i get 0 so i can't intent value from first activity right?

Comment: yes there is no key named `Intent` from first `Activity`. Try using `getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("Intent")` to check if the key exists or not.

Comment: It has a red line under "getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("Intent");"  It show that "Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to double"

Comment: `if(getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("Intent")){System.err.println("key exists")}else{System.err.println("key does not exist")}`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your double into a bundle, then passing like so

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Process.this,AddStudent.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in your new activity

```
 Bundle extras = Intent.getExtras();
 Double result = extras.getDouble("Intent");
```

Comment: intent.putExtras(b); what "b" refer to?

Comment: sorry, intent.putExtras(extras);